Is Li2CuSb thermoelectric?
In a fantastic 2019 Nature paper on unspervised auto-encoding (word2vec) of 3million chemistry/material science papers, the authors have found that the first 325 materials closest to the word of "thermoelectric" are all known to be indeed thermoelectric.
The 326th element, Li2CuSb, has (at the time) never been measured to be thermoelectric, and no publication mentions the connection between the material and the property "thermoelectricity".
My question: Is it now known whether Li2CuSb is indeed connected to thermoelectricity, either by computations or by experiments?

Does this make it the first, uninteresting thermoelectric? More seriously I haven't voted to close yet but I think the question could be improved by being more specific - I could throw a couple of Lithiums a Copper and an Antimony into CRYSTAL now and get a Seebeck coefficient out, and say it has, but that's not especially useful.

Just about any two conductors can produce thermoelectricity. Some pairs produce only a tiny voltage difference, such as platinum/rhodium-alloy thermocouples, which is very inefficient at generating power, yet is very useful, because they are stable at high temperature and the temperature/voltage relationship is quite consistent and repeatable. Even very low-power, low-efficiency devices can be useful, such as a copper-nickel (copel) vs. stainless steel thermocouple,  generating just 30 mV, in a gas shut-off valve.
So could $\ce{Li2CuSb}$ be a useful thermoelectric material? Quite likely! Would it be efficient for generating electric power, and over what temperature regime (e.g., relatively high-temperature radioisotope thermoelectric generator (RTG), lower-temperature home refrigeration)? Does it have other specialized thermoelectric properties? As you state, this seems to be a good area for research and experimentation.

Thanks a lot, very insightful!
